# Equation for everything?

Tags: time, universe, determinism

Suppose, I throw a ball and it bounce. If we observe it from the time of it hitting the ground, we can see it moves due to the initial velocity it had and the interaction it had with the ground. We can also predict where it would go next. In the same way, If we think little more complex and consider every particle in the universe, each particle should be moving with some initial velocity caused by something happened before, due to some other particle. Same is everywhere and if all the particles are considered from beginning of time, it all moves due to some start and follow changes in position and velocity dew to the fundamental forces interactions. If its true, each particles' motion can be processed into a single function, involving time and some other details like where the particle were at previous times, and such details. If it too is possible, we can find everything that happened in past, present and future, just by inserting some values for time in the function. Let the equation be any much complex, my question is, is such an equation possible? I have not heard of such a concept before. Is it already under some studies? Or is it marked as impossible or something? I am asking because I don't know about any branch that studies this thing. Kindly reply.

Comment: "*little more complex*" $\Rightarrow$ "*consider every particle in the universe*"...

Comment: Life is little bit more complicated because there is [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics)...

Comment: This is hugely too broad as a question, but the search term you are looking for is 'determinism'.  It turns out to be the case that even if physics is deterministic this is not useful for prediction of many systems: look up 'the electron at the edge of the universe'.

Comment: You couldn't even do that if the world were running by the rules of classical mechanics because all but about a dozen trivial Hamiltonian systems are non-integrable, which means that one can't calculate the long term future/past without the calculation errors blowing up to 100% of the result.

Answer (score 2):

> If we think little more complex and consider every particle in the universe, each particle should be moving with some initial velocity caused by something happened before, due to some other particle

You do not state the level of your physics knowledge. I will assume you are a highschool student.

What you are describing is the way [classical mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_mechanics) describes the behavior of particles. This evolved into statistical mechanics, i.e. the behavior of a large number of particles which is the reality in our universe. One mole of matter has ~10^23 particles. So even though classical mechanics allows for hypothetically knowing an enormous number of constants so that everything could be deterministic, in practice even in classical mechanics this is not possible, considering also the complications coming from forces as gravity and electromagnetism.

It gets worse, because in the microcosm of particles nature does not obey classical mechanics, but it follows [quantum mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_mechanics), which is a probabilistic theory and has an [inherent uncertainty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle) in measuring position and momentum, for example, so no constants could trace the behavior of individual particles. The quantum mechanical level is the fundamental level of nature , and the macroscopic behavior emerges from it.

The answer is that there is no such equation even in theory.

(In fairness it should be stated that there exist theorists who are trying to find a deterministic  underlying level from which quantum mechanics could emerge, but  it is not the mainstream physics research).